# Modal is not giving expected output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning modals. So i used this code from Jquery documentation but this code is not giving me the expected output. I could not find out what is wrong with this code? I want to get this type of output:
[image: Here is an axample]
But I am getting this output
[image: But I am getting this output]
Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="jane@smith.com" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

            <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
    <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
    <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
                <td>johndoe1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>


</body>
</html>
```

here is the javascript part:

```
 <script>
   $( function() {
      var dialog, form,

  // From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
  emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-][a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
  name = $( "#name" ),
  email = $( "#email" ),
  password = $( "#password" ),
  allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
  tips = $( ".validateTips" );

  function updateTips( t ) {
  tips
    .text( t )
    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
  setTimeout(function() {
    tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
    }, 500 );
  }

  function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
  if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
    o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
    updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
      min + " and " + max + "." );
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
    }
  }

  function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
  if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
    o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
    updateTips( n );
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
  }

  function addUser() {
  var valid = true;
  allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

  valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
  valid = valid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
  valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

  valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
  valid = valid && checkRegexp( email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
  valid = valid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

  if ( valid ) {
    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" );
    dialog.dialog( "close" );
  }
  return valid;
}

dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 400,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Create an account": addUser,
    Cancel: function() {
      dialog.dialog( "close" );
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    form[ 0 ].reset();
    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  }
});

form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  addUser();
});

$( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
  dialog.dialog( "open" );
      });
   } );
</script>
```

Here is the stylesheet:

```
  <style>
    label, input {
        display: block;
    }

        input.text {
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            width: 95%;
            padding: .4em;
        }

    fieldset {
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: .6em 0;
    }

    div#users-contain {
        width: 350px;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }

        div#users-contain table {
            margin: 1em 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

            div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th {
                border: 1px solid #eee;
                padding: .6em 10px;
                text-align: left;
            }

    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error {
        padding: .3em;
    }

    .validateTips {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        padding: 0.3em;
    }
    </style>
```

please help me how to solve this problem.Please ignore my mistakes.

Comment: @SankarRaj I have added the expected output photo

Comment: Did you got any errors?

Comment: @SankarRaj I am not getting any errors. But this code is not giving expected output. I want to show the modal while i click the button but this is not showing the modal just showing the plain text

Answer (score 1):

It is working as your expectation.

```js
$(function() {
  var dialog, form,

    // From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
    emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-][a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
    name = $("#name"),
    email = $("#email"),
    password = $("#password"),
    allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(password),
    tips = $(".validateTips");

  function updateTips(t) {
    tips
      .text(t)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    setTimeout(function() {
      tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
    }, 500);
  }

  function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
    if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
      o.addClass("ui-state-error");
      updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " +
        min + " and " + max + ".");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
    if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
      o.addClass("ui-state-error");
      updateTips(n);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  function addUser() {
    var valid = true;
    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

    valid = valid && checkLength(name, "username", 3, 16);
    valid = valid && checkLength(email, "email", 6, 80);
    valid = valid && checkLength(password, "password", 5, 16);

    valid = valid && checkRegexp(name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter.");
    valid = valid && checkRegexp(email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com");
    valid = valid && checkRegexp(password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9");

    if (valid) {
      $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
        "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>");
      dialog.dialog("close");
    }
    return valid;
  }

  dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Create an account": addUser,
      Cancel: function() {
        dialog.dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      form[0].reset();
      allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
  });

  form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addUser();
  });

  $("#create-user").button().on("click", function() {
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
label,
input {
  display: block;
}

input.text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: .4em;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: .6em 0;
}

div#users-contain {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

div#users-contain table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

div#users-contain table td,
div#users-contain table th {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: .6em 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-state-error {
  padding: .3em;
}

.validateTips {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="jane@smith.com" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

        <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
        <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>


  <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
    <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
    <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
      <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John Doe</td>
          <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
          <td>johndoe1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this code is working on code snippet but when i copy this code and paste this to sublime Text editor the output changed to the previous one.